# Modify specific list of cells of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, cell

Suppose I have a numpy array and I want to change the values. I have a specific list of (x,y)-coordinates that indicate the cells that should get added an additional term. The code below does the job for me.

```
>>> import numpy as np

n = 4
M = np.ones([n,n])
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,0]
xy = list(zip(x,y))

alpha = 0.3

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(n):

        M[i,j] = alpha*M[i,j] + ((i,j) in xy)*(1-alpha)*3

>>> M
Out[1]: 
array([[0.3, 2.4, 0.3, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.3, 2.4, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2.4],
       [2.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]])
```

However, I think that there are less cumbersome ways to achieve the same thing. Could someone help me to get rid of the two for-loops, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 4

x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,0]

M = alpha*np.ones([n,n])
M[x,y] += (1-alpha)*3
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `np.add.at`.

Since `np.add` is a [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), it has a special method `at` that lets you do easy in-place operations like that.

```
M = np.ones([n,n]) * alpha

np.add.at(M, (x, y), (1-alpha)*3)

M
Out[]: 
array([[0.3, 2.4, 0.3, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.3, 2.4, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 2.4],
       [2.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and one them is:

```
M=M*alpha
for i,j in zip(x,y):
  M[i,j] +=(1-alpha)*3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple indexing for this:

```
M = np.ones((n,n))
N = np.zeros((n, n))

N[x, y] = np.ones(len(x))

M = alpha * M + N * (1 - alpha) * 3
```

or

```
N = np.zeros((n, n))
N[x, y] = np.ones(len(x))

M = np.where(N, alpha + (1 - alpha) * 3, alpha)
```